# How to crop drawing to path

Tags: inkscape

I've been using Inkscape for a while, but I'm trying to remove everything covered by the red circles retaining only the blue curves in this drawing [[image: Blue curves and red circles1]. The blue curves and the red circles are grouped objects. Nothing I have tried (eraser tool, cut path, ...) gives me what I want. All suggestions welcome!
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

1. Ungroup everything several times to make sure there are no groups left. Boolean operations require two paths to work on. They won't work properly with multiple paths or groups of multiple paths/objects.
2. Select the blue circles and do *Path > Combine*. This makes a single combined path. Make sure this path is at the bottom of the stack by hitting the Lower to Bottom button in the controls bar [image] or use the shortcut <kbd>End</kbd>. The path you want to cut needs to be at the bottom of the stack.
3. Select the red circles, and do *Path > Combine*, to create the second combined path
4. Select and copy <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> the red circles
5. Select everything and do *Path > Cut Path*. This will consume the red circles, and cut all the blue circles at the line intersections.
6. Do *Edit > Paste > In Place* to bring back the red circles temporarily to act as a guide for selecting in the next step
7. Using the Selector Tool <kbd>S</kbd>, hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and click and drag to draw the red selector line over all the pieces you want to delete, avoiding the blue lines you want to keep.
8. Hit <kbd>Delete</kbd>, select and delete any remaining pieces you missed.

Example showing steps 7 and 8

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had some issues with step 7, but managed to delete unwanted stuff manually. Ill explore a bit more and try the Julius Krumbiegel extension that Dabid Cau suggested below.

Answer (score 0):

Two additional ideas, based on the same principle : after ungrouping :

- select one blue circle and use *right clic > select same > stroke color* and do p*ath > combine*.
- select one pink circle and *right clic : select same > stroke color* and do path> union.
- lower blue path to bottom and select blue path and pink filled path and run this interesting [extension](https://inkscape.org/nl/%7Ejgk/%E2%98%85cut-and-remove-by-shape-extension) from Julius Krumbiegel. This will avoid selecting and removing unwanted bits after path > cut path.

Comment: Unable to get the "Cut and remove by shape" extension to actually do anything. The second step produced a rather nice path however.

Comment: It worked fine for me. did you actually select both blue and pink path and ensure pink path was atop blue one before running the extension ?

Comment: The extension produced error messages: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jsibert/.config/inkscape/extensions/cut_and_remove_by_shape.py", line 278, in <module>
    CutAndRemoveByShapeExtension().run()
  File "/usr/share/inkscape/extensions/inkex/base.py", line 131, in run
    self.save_raw(self.effect())
  File "/home/jsibert/.config/inkscape/extensions/cut_and_remove_by_shape.py", line 106, in effect
    inkex.command.inkscape(self.options.input_file, actions=actions)
AttributeError: module 'inkex' has no attribute 'command'